# Safe destructuring using nullish coalescing or optional chaining

Tags: javascript, destructuring, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

Currently I am using below code for destructuring:

```js
const myObj1 = {name: 'Abc'}
const {name} = myObj1
console.log(name)
const myObj2 = null
const {name2} = myObj2  // this will give error
```

Now, since we have optional chaining, I can do this:

```js
const myObj = {name: 'Abc'}
const {name} = myObj
console.log(name) // 'Abc'
const myObj2 = null
const name2 = myObj2?.myObj2
console.log(name2) // undefined
```

Is there a better way or safe method to destructure using nullish coalescing or optional chaining?

Comment: try this: `const {name2} = myObj2 ?? {}`

Comment: If you use `const name2 = myObj2?.name2`, and if `myObj2?.name2` is an object then you will end up having the same reference which might cause issues by any chance you mutate `name2`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`const name2 = myObj2?.myObj2` - this is NOT destructuring.

`myObj2?.myObj2` will return `undefined` which you are assigning to `name2`.

You can simply do

```js
const myObj2 = null;
const { name2 } = { ...myObj2 };
console.log(name2); // undefined
```

If you want to use nullish coalescing operator, then you should use it as shown below:

```js
const myObj2 = null
const {name2} =  myObj2 ?? {};
console.log(name2) // undefined
```

nullish coalescing operator will return the operand on the right side if `myObj2` is null or undefined, otherwise it will return the operand on the left side, which in your case is `myObj2`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing, but it not destructuring and not really efficient when you want to destructure multiple properties you can do this.

```js
const myObj = {name: 'Abc', email: "test"}
const {name,email} = myObj
console.log(name, email) // 'Abc' "test"
const myObj1 = null
const {name1,email1} = myObj1 || {} // or myObj1 ?? {}
console.log(name1,email1) // undefined undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `||`

```js
const myObj2 = null;
const {name2, name3} = myObj2 || {}
console.log(name2, name3);

const myObj3 = {name4: "name4"};
const {name4, name5} = myObj3 || {}
console.log(name4, name5);
```

Hope this help.